# NeoBundleでプラグインをインストールしたいのですが、エラーが…。

Tags: vim

neoBundleでプラグインをインストールしたいのですが、なぜかエラーを吐いてしまって、うまくいきません。

【具体的な現状の内容】
まず、vimを立ち上げて、以下のように勧告が出るので、yesでインストールしようとします…。（nerdtreeという有名なプラグインを入れようとしてます）

```
Not installed bundles:  ['nerdtree']
Install bundles now?
(y)es, [N]o:
```

問題はこのあとで、以下のようなエラーが吐かれます

```
Error detected while processing function neobundle#commands#check..neobundle#commands#install..neobundle#installer#update..<SNR>19_save_install_info..neobundle#util#w
ritefile:
line    7:
E482: Can't create file /Users/kayamelo/.vim/bundle/.neobundle/install_info
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Error detected while processing function neobundle#commands#check..neobundle#commands#install..neobundle#installer#update..<SNR>19_save_install_info..<SNR>19_save_loc
kfile:
line    7:
E482: Can't create file /Users/kayamelo/.vim/bundle/NeoBundle.lock
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

`install_info` と、 `NeoBundle.lock` というファイルが作れないよ！って出てきます。
はじめの `Error detected while processing function` も気になるのですが…。
かなりググったのですが、何が行けないのかよくわかりません。

よろしければご助言お願いします。

Comment: まずは `/Users/kayamelo/.vim/bundle/` ディレクトリが存在するのかどうか、存在する場合にはディレクトリのオーナーやパーミッションを確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ご指摘通り、
`.vim` や`.vimrc`あたりのパーミッション弄ったら出来ました。
ありがとうございます。

あと、markdown形式の編集推奨もありがとうございます。
@unarist

Comment: @taka 未回答のままなので出来ればご自身で回答をポスト頂けないでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

コメントより:

> まずは /Users/kayamelo/.vim/bundle/ ディレクトリが存在するのかどうか、存在する場合にはディレクトリのオーナーやパーミッションを確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。 – user4986

---

> ご指摘通り、 .vim や.vimrcあたりのパーミッション弄ったら出来ました。  -taka